# NHibernate new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false, false);  No fourth bool parameter

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to follow the NHibernate tutorial, "Your first NHibernate based applicaton:Revision #4" at NHibernate Forge.

But the line: `new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false, false);`

Will not compile because it says there is no overload that takes four boolean paramaeters!

I am using NHibernate 2.1.2 in Visual Studio 2008 C#.  All the samples I have seen clearly
use this call with four boolean parameters.  Has something changed in the latest version of
NHibernate with the call to `SchemaExport()`?

I am trying to create a simple table in my database in a test method.  I am using MS SQL Express 2008 as my database.  I have tried the `Create(true, true)` call and it at least compiles and runs, but the table never seems to persist in the database.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it [changed from NH2.0.xGA to NH2.1.0](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/releasenotes.txt#L2554):

> In SchemaExport.Execute the parameter "format" was removed; (NH-1701) enabled configuration property format_sql (default true)

It used to be:

```
void Execute(bool script, bool export, bool justDrop, bool format)
```

Now it's:

```
void Execute(bool script, bool export, bool justDrop)
```

so just remove the `format` parameter. This was replaced by the `format_sql` config property:

```
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
```

[Here's the corresponding issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1701).

Answer (score -1):

Add this item:

```
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;
```